# Identifying topological relationships using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql, topology

I'm trying to perform a basic typology analysis using PostGIS. My objective is to find any polygons that touch other polygons. To do this, I thought the `ST_GetFaceEdges` would work
([reference](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ST_GetFaceEdges.html)). I want to check every polygon in my database and list all the other polygons that touch it. In the image below I would expect the result to say that two of the polygons (which are buildings) touch one building, and the results of the other 4 to say that they touch 0 polygons.

[image]

However, I'm having some difficulty understanding what to do. When I tried to copy the example there were a few parts of it that I did not understand.

```
-- Returns the sequence, edge id
-- , and geometry of the edges that bound face 1
-- If you just need geom and seq, can use ST_GetFaceGeometry
SELECT t.seq, t.edge, geom
FROM topology.ST_GetFaceEdges('tt',1) As t(seq,edge)
    INNER JOIN tt.edge AS e ON abs(t.edge) = e.edge_id;
```

I'm not sure whether `topology` is the name of a table, column or a part of the function. I assumed that it was the table, but I'm not sure.

```
-- try out on sample of data
-- Table is called 'TestArea', column used is 'fid_1'
SELECT t.seq, t.edge, geom
FROM  TestArea.ST_GetFaceEdges('fid_1', 1) As t(seq,edge)
    INNER JOIN tt.edge AS e ON abs(t.edge) = e.edge_id;
```

I'm also not sure what the function of the inner join is - does this join the result to the original object?

Comment: I know underdark has answered this with her characteristically clear diagrams, but something I'm not sure on is whether your polygons are topologically related in the first place. Topology, in this case, implies a logical relationship between entities as separate from their visual representation, and (in PostGIS) requires setting up a schema with `CreateTopology` and so on (http://bit.ly/oLk8QY) But the way your buildings are digitised looks to me like they are topologically distinct despite the visual closeness of their edges. Just something for future questioners to be aware of.

Comment: Would this mean that I need to add a `AddTopoGeometryColumn` to the table before running the query? Based on the results from `ST_Touches` the values I checked all made sense but perhaps that was by chance.

Comment: Not only would you need to call `AddTopoGeometryColumn`, but your data would need to be digitized in a topologically consistent way. For instance, traditionally you would digitise two semi-detached houses as two polygons and use "snap to vertex" in your GIS to ensure the shared wall touches, but it will be stored as two coincident lines with coincident points at each end. But topologically digitizing them means that the shared wall really is just one line and two nodes shared by each polygon. `ST_Touches` just does a spatial check for closeness, not a topological one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [ST_Touches](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Touches.html) instead:

> ST_Touches — Returns TRUE if the geometries have at least one point in common, but their interiors do not intersect.

ST_Touches returns TRUE for eg

[image]

Getting the counts should work something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, count(*)
FROM polygon_table as a
JOIN polygon_table as b
  ON ST_Touches(a.the_geom,b.the_geom)
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: I am interested in knowing how many polygons each polygon touches though. Otherwise it is perfect, and I got it to run!

Comment: I just realized it returns a true/false value for every case so all I need to do is count how many true values are there. Thanks!

Comment: Added a possible counting query.